# jQuery previous button when clicked goes back to Q.) 1 rather then going backward one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

jQuery previous button not working as expected.
Basically the best way to explain it is if I'm on question 5 and I click the previous button, it defaults to question 1 rather than going to question 4.

So it's defaulting to question 1... That's a problem.
What to do?

jQuery is in the bottom in script tags.

```
  if (i.Question_Type == "DROPDOWN")
  {
    <div class="container text-center">

      <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
        @{
          counter++;
        }

        <div id="question1" class="form-group">
          <label class="lab text-center" for="form-group-select">
            @i.Question_Order @Html.Raw(@i.Question)
          </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="form-group-select">
            @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
            {
              var t = x - 1;
              if (i.qOps != null)
              {
                <option> @i.qOps.options[t]</option>
              }
              else
              {
                <option> @x</option>
              }
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }

  if (i.Question_Type == "RADIO")
  {

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
        @{counter++;
        }
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="lab" for="questions">
            @i.Question_Order @i.Question
          </label>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div id="question1" class="radio-inline">
                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                {
                  var t = x - 1;
                  if (i.qOps != null)
                  {
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="question"> @i.qOps.options[t]</label>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" min="0" max="@x" name="question"></label>
                  }
                }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  }
  if (i.Question_Type == "CHECKBOX")
  {
    for (int y = 1; y <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); y++)
    {
      @*<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <label>@y</label>   <input type="checkbox" name="question">

      </div>
      </div>*@
    }
  }
}
<div class="azibsButtons">
  <button type="button" id="previous"  class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</button>

  <button type="button" id="next"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

    var inner = $(this).data('questions');
    if (inner == 0) {

      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');

    }
  });
  $("#next").click(function () {

    $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

      var inp = $(this);
      if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
        var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
        dataVal++;
        inp.addClass('hidden');

        $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

        return false;

      }
    });

    $("#previous").click(function () {

      $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

        var inp = $(this);
        if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
          var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
          dataVal--;
          inp.addClass('hidden');

          $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

          return false;

        }
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html as well?

Comment: Okay i'm doing it right now

Comment: Is there a reason why the previous click event is inside the next click event?

Comment: it's not inside the next click event to my knowledge

Comment: from your code, it clearly is... this means that the previous event will only be available after the next event is fired, and overwritten every time.

Comment: Daniel you were right the next click event was covering the previous event also. the problem has been resolved Thank you!

Comment: Daniel i have one more question for you, how can I make the previous button hidden on question 1. I do Not want the previous button to be there since its the first question, once next is clicked then display previous

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the solution Thanks to Daniel.

The next event closing braces were wrapped around the previous event, which caused the problem to default to question 1 when clicked previous.

```
$("#next").click(function () {

  $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

    var inp = $(this);
    if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
      var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
      dataVal++;
      inp.addClass('hidden');

      $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

      return false;
    }
  });
});

$("#previous").click(function () {

  $(".idrow").each(function (i) {

    var inp = $(this);
    if (!inp.hasClass('hidden')) {
      var dataVal = inp.data("questions");
      dataVal--;
      inp.addClass('hidden');

      $('[data-questions=' + dataVal + ']').removeClass('hidden');

      return false;
    }
  });
});
```